# React error saying Objects are not valid as react child

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting the [Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {counter, num}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.] error for the below code :

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0,
    num : 0
}
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "INCREMENT":
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    counter: state.counter + action.payLoad
                }
            }
            case "DECREMENT":
                return {
                    ...state,
                    counter: state.counter - action.payLoad
                }
        default:
            {
                return state;
            }
    }
}
export default counterReducer;
```

If I do like below everything working fine:

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "INCREMENT":
            return  state + action.payLoad;
        case "DECREMENT":
            return state - action.payLoad;
        default:
            {
                return state;
            }
    }
}

export default counterReducer;
```

Comment: Make sure you update the consumed value in your component to be something like `counterReducer.counter` and not just `counterReducer`. You've changed the state from a number to an object so the component should reflect that.

Comment: Your counterReducer is having an object, your working version has a Number. In your render try    `counterReducer.counter`

Answer (score 1):

You probably try to render somewhere the counter? Your default case returns the entire object, instead of just `state.counter`.
Try it like this:

```
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENT":
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter + action.payLoad
            }
        }
        case "DECREMENT":
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter - action.payLoad
            }
    default:
        {
            return state.counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Or in the component where you render it access the object property `state.counter`

Comment: Thank you for answering and that is correct the reducer actually returns an Object..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the reducer you've written.

Without the corresponding component code and based on the error you're seeing, it seems that you're using the entire state object (`{ counter: 0, num: 0 }`, for example) within the React component that's using the state from this reducer.

Replacing the object (`{ counter: 0, num: 0 }`, from the above example) with just the counter value (`obj.counter`) should get it working